# PHPExcel Не читает строки из xlsx

Tags: php, phpexcel, xlsx

Здравствуйте, имеется файл импорта (неизвестно как сгенерирован) xlsx (2007).
Файл в принципе читается, но сыпется ошибка на Excel2007.php(851)

```
$value = $sharedStrings[intval($c->v)];
```

И не может прочитать строковые данные из файла. Все числовые значения читаются на ура (формат везде общий).
При этом, стоит открыть xslx и просто сохранить (ctrl+s), как каким-то чудом всё начинает прекрасно работать и читаться.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой ?

Comment: Проблема решена (обновлением PHPExcel).

Comment: В xlsx tcnm 2 формата строк - shared и заинлайненные в ячейки. Предположу, что файл может содержать заинлайненные.

Comment: Да там как раз так и было, но вопрос всё равно остаётся почему всё начинало работать после простого сохранения ?)

Comment: Написал ответом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> $value = $sharedStrings[intval($c->v)];
> ```

В xlsx есть 2 формата строк - shared и заинлайненные в ячейки. Предположу, что файл может содержать заинлайненные. В таком случае совершенно логично, что они отсутствуют в shared.

> почему всё начинало работать после простого сохранения ?)

Потому что Excel при сохранении файла его полностью перезаписывает. А он сам никогда (по крайней мере, мне не встречалось) не использует заинлайненные строки. Поэтому после сохранения получалось, что все строки находятся в shared и код начинал работать.